# Find the rows placement based on a condition

Tags: mysql, sql

This might be an easy one, but I cant figure out how. Lets say this is my table:

```
ID Name   Amount
1  John   4
2  Peter  16
3  Martha 23
4  Carl   41
5  Sarah  3
```

When I sort it by amount descending, my table looks like this:

```
ID Name   Amount
4  Carl   41
3  Martha 23
2  Peter  16
1  John   4
5  Sarah  3
```

How can I find out which number from top  i.e. John is when I order by amound descending? He should be 4th.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Should've added that. MySQL.

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: I am using version 8.0.19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` or `rank()`:

```
select t.*, rank() over (order by amount desc) as ranking
from t;
```

Note:  This uses `rank()` so rows with the same amount have the same `ranking`.  If you actually want ties to have different numbers, then use `row_number()` -- but be cautioned:  the `ranking` for tied values may change from one run to the next because the database has no way to distinguish the tied values.

Comment: How can I use that now to get/show only Johns ranking in that list?

Comment: @Peterbrannstrom . . . You can use a subquery and select "John" in the outer query.